# AutoFixture: resolving IEnumerable<T>, Unable to cast object of type 'ConvertedEnumerable` to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, moq, autofixture

I tried to use AutoFixture to generate test data for classes that have IEnumerable members.

**AutoFixture test code :**

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<NotificationDto>(c => c.Without(r => r.IntegrationModel));
NotificationDto notificationDto = fixture.Create<NotificationDto>();
```

**Class :**

```
public class NotificationDto 
{
    public NotificationDto() 
    {
        To = new List<RecipientDto>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IIntegrationEventModel IntegrationModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RecipientDto> To { get; set; }
}
```

**During debugging of code**
[image]

```
 public CreateNotificationCommand(NotificationDto notificationDto)
    {
        ...
        To = (List<RecipientDto>)(notificationDto.To ?? new List<RecipientDto>());
    }
```

**Getting below error :**

```
 UpdateNotificationFromAwsSnsCommandHandlers_UpdateNotificationToSuccess
   Duration: 8.9 sec

  Message: 
    System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'ConvertedEnumerable`1[Notification.Core.Notification.Dto.SolrDto.RecipientSolrDto]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Notification.Core.Notification.Dto.SolrDto.RecipientSolrDto]'.

  Stack Trace: 
    CreateNotificationCommand.ctor(NotificationDto notificationDto) line 31
    UpdateNotificationFromAwsSnsCommandHandlersTester.SetAutoData_UpdateNotificationFromAwsSnsCommandHandlers_UpdateNotificationToNotDelivered() line 60
    UpdateNotificationFromAwsSnsCommandHandlersTester.UpdateNotificationFromAwsSnsCommandHandlers_UpdateNotificationToSuccess() line 75
    GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()
    AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
    TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
    TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
    c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0()
    BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)
```

Please help me?

Comment: It seems like all you need is `To = (notificationDto.To ?? new List<RecipientDto>()).AsEnumerable();`

Answer (score 1):

`To` is an `IEnumerable`, so it is not guaranteed to be a `List`, so this cast is not guaranteed to work (in your unit test AutoFixture does not create a list, for example). You can change your code to:

```cs
To = notificationDto.To ?? Enumerable.Empty<RecipientDto>();
```

or something like:

```
To = notificationDto.To as List<RecipientDto> 
    ?? notificationDto.To?.ToList() 
    ?? new List<RecipientDto>();
```

Or change the signature of `To` to `List<RecipientDto>`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because `notificationDto.To` isn't necessarily `List<RecipientDto>` at runtime, it can be an array of `RecipientDto` or any other type implicitly casted to `IEnumerable<RecipientDto>`. Hence, when `notificationDto.To` has different runtime type from `List<RecipientDto>` the `InvalidCastException` is thrown.

To fix this you can either just remove casting to the list and everything should work fine or have `Enumerable.Empty<RecipientDto>()` on the right side of the operator (**for both only if `To` on the right side of `=` is `IEnumerable<RecipientDto>`**):

```
1. To = notificationDto.To ?? new List<RecipientDto>();
2. To = notificationDto.To ?? Enumerable.Empty<RecipientDto>();
```

The first approach works because the result type of the expression in this case will be `IEnumerable<RecipientDto>`. This follows from the specification for the operator `??` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1114-the-null-coalescing-operator.

We're interested in this part of the spec:

> if `A` is not a nullable type (**but a reference type**) and an implicit conversion exists from `b` to `A`, the result type is `A`. At run-time, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not `null`, `a` becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and converted to type `A`, and this becomes the result.`

Where `A` is the type of `a`.

In your case `a` is `notificationDto.To` and `b` is `new List<RecipientDto>()`, therefore `A` is `IEnumerable<RecipientDto>`. Since `IEnumerable<RecipientDto>` is not a nullable type and there is a conversion from `new List<RecipientDto>` to `IEnumerable<RecipientDto>` the result type of the expression will be also `IEnumerable<RecipientDto>`. Hence if `To` is already `IEnumerable<RecipientDto>` you don't need to do any casting.